# How to use else if logical function using dynamic content in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to add another if condition on else part of if condition but its showing "function 'if' does not accept 1 argument(s)"

**dynamic content:**

@{if(equals(activity('CopyCSVToTable').output.rowsRead,activity('CopyCSVToTable').output.rowsCopied),'completed',if(greater(activity('CopyCSVToTable').output.rowsCopied,0)),'partially_completed','failed'))}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra brackett. Can you try this?

```
@{if(equals(activity('CopyCSVToTable').output.rowsRead,activity('CopyCSVToTable').output.rowsCopied),'completed',if(greater(activity('CopyCSVToTable').output.rowsCopied,0),'partially_completed','failed'))}
```

Comment: Thanks @Anupam its working